# how to fix UUID mismatch when *repeatedly* converting RAW disk image to VirtualBox image format?

Tags: virtualbox, qemu, diskimage

In a Docker container I'm creating a full PC Linux image from scratch (using `debootstrap` and lots of other tools).

At the end of the process I'm using `qemu-img convert -f raw -O vdi infile.raw outfile.vdi` to generate a image file suitable for VirtualBox.

That works in essence - the disk boots inside VirtualBox.

However, when creating a *new* image and **replacing** `outfile.vdi` (of course with the VM powered off), then VirtualBox complains that the disk image is not okay because the UUID does not match the one stored in the VirtualBox media registry.

I am forced to remove and add the file again in the VM settings using the VirtualBox GUI so that I can start the VM again.

I guess there is some (random) `UUID` stored directly in the `.vdi` file, but I could not find a way to manually specify a fixed UUID with `qemu-img`.

How can I solve this problem? Perhaps another VirtualBox-compatible disk format would work better?

*In case it matters: This all happens under a Windows host*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the answer here: [How to change UUID in virtual box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803331/how-to-change-uuid-in-virtual-box) helped. I do it like this:

1. Issue the `VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid my-drive.vdi` on the drive in question
2. Using the output UUID value and replace it in the VMs `.vbox` file (in my case, in two places).

May be it is not quite good a way, as I restart VirtualBox, not tried to do it "live", but hopefully this answer will useful for someone.

Of course, the script can be made to do it automatically.

Also, [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=33678) says uuid can be given as a parameter to `VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid <UUID> <Yourdrive>`, but I have not tried as my task is not frequent one. The way to do it fully in a script given there.

Comment: The command is `VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid "/path/to.vdi" "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX"`. And it works well.